# Chrome drive broken?

Tags: web-access

[image]
I tried this external session, as `Import["Url"]` is sometimes blocked by websites. But it is down now, and I really don't know why. My computer is Dell XPS 13 with windows 10 and the latest version of chrome.

Comment: The `bug` tag should be used only when it is established that there is actually a bug

Comment: @mattiav27 thanks

Comment: FWIW, it works for me. Has it ever worked for you?

Comment: If this is reliably reproducible after a [clean start](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) you should [contact technical support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical).

Comment: 1) Please paste copy/pastable code; 2) I cannot execute the first line of code `session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"]` because " "WebDriver-Chrome" is not a known language in the ExternalEvaluate Framework". Have you left out any instructions / code one should run first?

Comment: It works like a charm for me with the latest version of Chrome and *Mathematica* 11.3 on Windows 7 x64: every example from the [Docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html) page works. Try reinstalling Chrome.